# Is it possible to get HTML content between a 'using'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have created a new HTML helper with a ctor and a Dispose function, and during the time my control is initialised I write some HTML. Like this:

```
<% using(Html.BeginScript()) { %>
    var jan = "hoi";
    alert(jan);
<% } %>
```

Is there any way to grab the inner HTML there? Overriding the `TextWriter` doesn't work:

```
public class MvcScriptWrapper: IDisposable
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _ms;
    private readonly TextWriter _tw;
    private readonly TextWriter _originalTw;

    public MvcScriptWrapper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _ms = new MemoryStream();
        _tw = new StreamWriter(_ms);

        _originalTw = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer;

        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer = _tw;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _tw.Flush();

        _ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string content;
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_ms))
        {
            originalTw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }

        _tw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same exact issue. I need to access stream that Viewcontext's textwriter and edit it programatically

Comment: Hi, yeah, check out the source of [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** To solve these kind of problems I wrote a library called [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth). Besides making your websites fast, it also supports a plugin architecture that hooks into the MVC page flow (MVC 2 and 3) that you can use to apply HTML postprocessing. For an example, see [this executor](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/blob/master/Core/Modules/OutputSubstitution/OutputSubstitutionExecutor.cs).

Call this function to register your post processor.

```
MothAction.RegisterExecutor(new YourExecutor());
```

---

Setting the `InnerWriter` works:

```
// ctor

_originalTw = ((HtmlTextWriter)htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer).InnerWriter;
((HtmlTextWriter)htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer).InnerWriter = _tw;
```